# too much recursion error firefox only

Tags: javascript, firefox, recursion

I am getting too much recursion error in firefox. The code is working in Chrome. I assume because of this code:

```
if ($visible.outerWidth() > spaceAvail) {
        NavTabs.updateOnResize();
    }
```

The error occur in this page http://praxistipps.chip.de/rubrik/android.

UPDATE:
This is the main function that is causing the error in firefox.

```js
var NavTabs,
    $nav = $('.NavTabs'),
    $toggle = $nav.find('.NavTabs__Toggle'),
    $visible = $nav.find('.NavTabs__Visible'),
    $hidden = $nav.find('.NavTabs__Hidden'),
    classHidden = 'is-hidden',
    breaks = [];
    
updateOnResize: function updateOnResize() {
        var spaceAvail = $toggle.hasClass(classHidden) ? $nav.outerWidth() : $nav.outerWidth() - $toggle.outerWidth(); // eslint-disable-line

        $hidden.attr('style', 'min-width:' + $toggle.outerWidth() + 'px');

        if ($visible.outerWidth() > spaceAvail) {
            breaks.push($visible.outerWidth());
            $visible.children().last().prependTo($hidden);
            if ($toggle.hasClass(classHidden)) {
                $toggle.removeClass(classHidden);
            }
        } else {
            if (spaceAvail > breaks[breaks.length - 1]) {
                $hidden.children().first().appendTo($visible);
                breaks.pop();
            }
            if (breaks.length < 1) {
                $toggle.addClass(classHidden);
                $hidden.addClass(classHidden);
            }
        }
        if ($visible.outerWidth() > spaceAvail) {
            NavTabs.updateOnResize();
        }
    }
```

```html
<nav class="NavTabs">
    <button class="NavTabs__Toggle">Weitere Kategorien</button>
        <ul class="NavTabs__Visible"></ul>
        <ul class="NavTabs__Hidden is-hidden"></ul>
    </nav>
```

How do I fix this? . Any help or hint would be great.

Comment: How can anyone tell without knowing what any of the values are?

Comment: I don't see any recursion in the example you've given. Please provide a _[mcve]_.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ya3w834s/1/

Comment: Please add all relevant code _inside the question itself_.

Comment: Yes I had the similar issue

Comment: The error occur in this page http://praxistipps.chip.de/rubrik/android